# How can I download an S3 binary file using Amazon's AWS CLI tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to download a binary file from an AWS S3 bucket using Amazon's new [command-line interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).  However, the tool responds with an error message.

```
$ aws s3 get-object --bucket myBucketName --key myFileName

<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x1e61710> is not JSON serializable
```

Specifying text output format, gives the object's metadata, but again not the actual data.

```
$ aws --output text get-object --bucket myBucketName --key myFileName
<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x298f710>   Fri, 05 Apr 2013 18:11:47 GMT   bytes   application/x-rpm       310000
```

The [tests](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/tests/unit/s3/test_get_object.py) in the tool's source code distribution don't seem to exercise this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for posting.
It's a known bug - you obviously know it by now since you're the one that posted it :)
anyway, if anyone needs an update check here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/86 anyone know an alternative or workaround?

Comment: You can obviously download the fixed version from  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli

Comment: It looks like the github bug was closed.  Would you add an answer here and then accept it so this question doesn't hang around unanswered forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the behaviour was due to a [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/86), which has since been [fixed](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/commit/3a94dd3ff739b6032f10f34597462de56e96c35d).